# Count most occurring word in row SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the number of times a certain word occur in a query row.

For example :

```
Name   | Chemistry | Physics   | Biology   | Maths
-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+--------
John   | Excellent | Good      | Good      | Poor
Kelvin | Excellent | Excellent | Excellent | Poor
```

I want to get something for each row like

```
Name   | Excellent | Good | Poor
-------+-----------+------+-------
John   |    1      |   2  |   1
Kelvin |    3      |   0  |   1
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add them up using `case` expressions:

```
select name,
       (case when chemistry = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when physics = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when biology = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when math = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end
       ) as num_excellents,
       . . .
from t;
```

A fancier method would use `apply` and aggregation:

```
select t.name, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select sum(case when marks = 'Excellent' then 1 else 0 end) as excellent,
             sum(case when marks = 'Good' then 1 else 0 end) as good,
             sum(case when marks = 'Poor' then 1 else 0 end) as Poor      
      from (values (chemistry), (physics), (biology), (math)
           ) v(marks);
```

Comment: Nice! Is there a way I can add an if statement to check the word that **appeared** most.

Comment: The case statements in the first select need a end though.. ;-)

Comment: @AssuranceFemi . . . That would be a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.  Be sure to explain what you want when there are ties.